# Moving Input Decoration to left in InternationalPhoneNumberInput widget

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I want to move  Input Decoration to left in InternationalPhoneNumberInput widget. How can I do this? Pic 1 is what I want to do, Pic 2 is what i am stuck at and this is my current code for widget.

```
InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
                        textStyle: black14RegularTextStyle,
//                        autoValidate: false,
                        autoValidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                        selectorTextStyle: black16MediumTextStyle,
                        initialValue: number,
                        textFieldController: controller,
                        inputBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
//                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
                          hintText: 'Phone Number',
                          hintStyle: black14RegularTextStyle,
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          isDense: true,  ///added
                        ),
//                        selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.DIALOG,
                        selectorConfig: SelectorConfig(selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.DIALOG),
                        onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber number) {
                          print(number.phoneNumber);
                        },
                      ),
```

[image: this is what I want to achieve]

[image: This is what i am stuck at]

package link:
https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_number_input/example

Comment: Can you include the package link on question

Answer (score 1):

Add the following parameter to it:-

```
spaceBetweenSelectorAndTextField: 0,
```